# AWS deploying strategy for cached page/app

Tags: amazon-web-services, cache, deployment, node.js, elastic-beanstalk

We have a Single Page App with server-side rendering enabled. We hosted on AWS ELB.

The application assets (`js`, `css` files) has a hash in the filename, to control the caching on the client/proxy sides and be able to make sure, that since new build has arrived, every our customer will get a new version of it.

To be performed well, we've decided to cache the whole document with the header, body, and footer everything. It's kinda pre rendered (with all components) result which is stored in the cache. It works pretty well, but there is an issue.

No matter what deployment strategy we use we face it, all the time. We have two instances, and since we deploy a new build to one of the instances with Rolling method (which is recommended by AWS) we invalidate the `Memcache`, but the problem is: the instance which has not been updated yet (previous build), is working (handling the requests). It means if the old instance will receive a request faster than the new one (what happens sometimes), then we will get in the cache old version of the document, which refers to non-existing assets (with the old hash in the filename).

I see couple solutions:
1. start using simple filename for the assets (avoid hashes)
2. don't use `memcache` until all the instances is updated
both of them are not fit in the requirements what we have.

Is there any other solution(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use blue/green deployments with sticky load balancing, but I wonder if it'd be reliable enough. In theory a percentage of your traffic would go to the new server, including requests for static resources.

Another option is to deploy the static assets onto all servers, then do a rolling deploy of the code. I wouldn't use cache busting techniques here, I'd use filenames to indicate asset versions. This means you can cache static assets for a long time but still easily move to new versions when you deploy.

Another option could be to serve all traffic from one machine, update the other machine, then do a switch / cutover.

It really depends on your application, your load, and your preferences. Maybe one of the ideas above will work for you, or at least give you some options to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well blue/green deployment has another issue DNS propagation timeout, therefore some clients still are requesting an old build from the old server.

what is that switch/cutover? how to do it?

Comment: It looks like the way you have things set up you can't do incremental deploys. Is memcached on one server, or does it run on each server? I think you need to change your architecture so you can run with different versions, which means servers should work more or less standalone.

Comment: Running an instance on each server would be less efficient but easier for deploys. AWS has a lot of [blue/green info in this white paper](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Blue_Green_Deployments.pdf), you'll have to read it and weigh up everything you know. We don't know your environment well enough to tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: Yep, you're right you don't know enough about our env. Anyway thanks for the doc. I think I got an idea.